# How to enable specific column in a devexpress gridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress-gridcontrol

my code seems to be not working

```
gridView6.Columns["QueueID"].OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;
```

I also tried

```
 int n = Convert.ToInt32(gridView6.Columns.Count.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            gridView6.Columns["QueueID"].OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;
        }
```

I have tried these codes but my gridview still does not allow editing after executing my winform, Is there other way to make this work? because my code does not catch any errors

Comment: Make sure: gridView6.Columns["QueueID"].OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = false;

Answer (score 0):

> AllowEdit is in effect if the View's ColumnView.Editable property is set to true.

Check if you enabled [ColumnViewOptionsBehavior.Editable Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnViewOptionsBehavior.Editable.property).